# Join on 2 different keys

Tags: sql

I need to join 2 Tables, but these tables have 2 pair of keys which need to be joined.

ID,Car and Color is one "pair" and than the `OTHERID`.

```
LEFT JOIN TableTest t2 ON
    (t1.ID = t2.ID)
    AND
    (t1.CAR = t2.CAR)
    AND (t1.Color = t2.Color)
```

I have tried now to add the `OTHERID` key to the statement as:

```
LEFT JOIN TableTest t2 ON
    (t1.ID = t2.ID)
    AND
    (t1.CAR = t2.CAR)
    AND
    (t1.Color = t2.Color)
    OR
    (t1.OTHERID = t2.OTHERID);
```

But that doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You're overlooking the operator-precedence of `AND` vs `OR`.

If `t1.OTHERID = t2.OTHERID` should come first then promote it like so (you also don't need to parenthesize every expression):

```
LEFT JOIN TableTest t2 ON
    t1.OTHERID = t2.OTHERID
    OR
    (
        t1.ID = t2.ID
        AND
        t1.CAR = t2.CAR
        AND
        t1.Color = t2.Color
    );
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if one pair of keys = NULL? That can happend, i think that causes the problems i have.

Comment: what do you mean by "pair of keys = NULL"? Please post actual example data.

Comment: The ID,CAR,Color is a "set1 of key" and on the other hand the OTHERID is "set2". 
So it could be that set1 = NULL and than OTHERID IS NOT NULL or reverse. Thats why i need the 2 key pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with your brackets.

```
LEFT JOIN TableTest t2 ON (t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.CAR = t2.CAR AND t1.Color = t2.Color) OR t1.OTHERID = t2.OTHERID
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if one pair of keys = NULL? That can happend, i think that causes the problems i have.